# Proof of integration by substitution directly from the definition of Riemann integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

> Theorem 1:
>   If $f : [a, b] \to [c, d]$ is a $C^1$ function and $g : [c, d] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $$\int_{a}^{b} g(f(x))f'(x) dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(y) dy.$$

I want to prove this theorem directly from the definition of Riemann integral.

If $f$ is a monotonically increasing or decreasing function on $[a, b]$, then I guess the proof of Theorem 1 is easy.

Are there real numbers $x_0, \cdots, x_n$ such that $a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b$ and $f$ is increasing or decreasing on $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ for any $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ if $f$ is $C^1$?

If there exist such real numbers $x_0, \cdots, x_n$, I guess the proof of Theorem 1 is easy.

Comment: ".. if $g$ is $C^1$?" Did you mean $g$ is $C^0$ because the hypothesis of the Theorem only requires that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @ZeroXLR I am sorry. I edited.

Comment: By "directly from the definition" do you mean you don't want to use the fundamental theorem of calculus? That is the easiest proof under your strong assumptions and it does not require $f$ to be increasing.   Are you saying the proof is easy if $f$ is increasing or asking how it is done? It is not clear to me.  If $f$ is increasing then you can even relax the assumption that $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4):

**Proof using the fundamental theorem of calculus and no assumption of monotonicity for $f$**

Define $\displaystyle G(x) = \int_{f(a)}^{f(x)} g(t)\,dt$. Since $g$ is continuous, by the FTC we have

$$G'(x) =g(f(x))f'(x)$$

Since $G(a) = 0$ and $G'$ is integrable it follows that

$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(x)\,dx = G(b) = G(b)-G(a) = \int_a^bG'(x)\,dx = \int_a^bg(f(x))f'(x)\,dx$$

**Proof using the "definition of Riemann integral" when $f$ is increasing.**

It seems you are looking for a proof using Riemann sums when $f$ is increasing. I provide one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3089345/148510). This uses the mean value theorem and the fact that both $a < x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$ and $f(a) = f(x_0) < f(x_1) < \ldots < f(x_n) = f(b)$ define partitions.  Also, in this case, it is only required that $g$ is Riemann integrable.

The most general theorem, of which I am aware, does not require continuity of $g$ or $f'$, but is much more difficult to prove.